# Coldfusion: reading ñ with cfspreadsheet action="read"

Tags: coldfusion, internationalization, coldfusion-10

I am reading an excel file using:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#theFile#" 
        query="data" 
        headerrow="1">
```

However, when dumping the query, all instances of the letter `ñ` are converted to `n`. How can I prevent this translation?

Comment: ColdFusion 10 does not auto convert data like that. `<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="myexcelfile.xlsx" query="data"> <cfdump var="#data#" />` Check for possible other things in code.

Comment: Agreed, that result seems very unlikely. Can you post a small, *standalone* example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: A simple dump introduces the browser's interpretation of the text into the equation.  Use `<pre>` tags and such to verify that what you see is the actual data.  You can also loop through the characters and look at their ascii codes.

Comment: What does the actual data in the database look like? Is it storing the ñ character correctly or is the translation happening back there? Check the encoding of both the DB and CF Administrator. Actually, follow the encoding through the entire stack, from import to output of your spreadsheet. They should all match and contain the characters you're trying to translate.